# Sending HTTP cross-domain request with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to send a HTTP cross-domain request with PUT method with AJAX.

For that, I am using this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ipv6Nodo+"/config?param=led",          
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: "ls=ON",
    success: function(data) {
        // Do something with the result
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I am sniffing on the middle and I am seeing that I am really sending a request with OPTIONS method. That's not the problem, because on the server I can accept PUT or OPTIONS similarly. The problem is that the payload request is empty, there is not `ls=ON`, how I want it. If I throw this request to the same domain, I can see the payload. What's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Throw the request"*??

Comment: They make an options request first which asks if PUT is allowed. You should not be handling the options request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no payload to the `OPTIONS` request used with [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). It's a "preflight" request to find out whether the server allows CORS from your origin. Once you respond to the `OPTIONS` request with the correct CORS headers, you'll get the `PUT` request with the data.

See the link for details, but basically:

- Browser sends `OPTIONS` with CORS request headers.
- Server decides whether the request is acceptable from that origin, and if so responds with appropriate CORS response headers.
- Browser responds with the actual `PUT`.

This is transparent to your client-side `ajax` code (but not your server code).

Comment: So if I enable CORS on the server, I should be able to send a PUT request

Comment: Provided you're using a browser that [correctly supports CORS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), yes. So, not IE8 or IE9, which support it but through a special `XDomainRequest` object rather than `XMLHttpRequest`, a browser inconsistency that jQuery doesn't smooth over (though if you search, you can find code to do it).

Comment: Could you tell me how is a CORS response from the server? I know that it must have the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` but I don't know how should be the rest. Basically I'd like to know if it is a HTTP/1.1 200OK, or similar.

Comment: It must be a HTTP 204 No Content. Thanks for the help!